# Adding multiple rectangle patches using Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to add multiple rectangle patches (`rect1, rect2, rect3`)using `ax.add_patch` but it takes 2 positional arguments only. How can I implement this? The current and the expected outputs are presented.

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle

fig,ax = plt.subplots(1)
rect1 = mpl.patches.Rectangle((0,800),50, 20, linewidth=1, edgecolor='black', facecolor='black')
rect2 = mpl.patches.Rectangle((200,800),50, 20, linewidth=1, edgecolor='black', facecolor='black')
rect3 = mpl.patches.Rectangle((400,800),50, 20, linewidth=1, edgecolor='black', facecolor='black')
ax.add_patch(rect1)
ax.set_xlim(left = 0, right = 1000)
ax.set_ylim(bottom = 0, top = 1000)
plt.show()
```

The current output is

[image]

The expected output is

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to also add `rect2` and `rect3` to your figure: `ax.add_patch(rect2)` and `ax.add_patch(rect3)`. For now you only add `rect1`, hence the result.

Answer (score 0):

For those of you coming here because you cannot see both of the rectangles, try changing the axis limits of the graph.

Thank you @Wiz123 for including that portion in your question I didn't even realize that it doesn't automatically scale for rectangles.